# mysqli_query returning error

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Hi I'm very new to php and my query to my mysql database is returning an error. My connection is fine, but there's something wrong with my query. I've run it through php validators but they can't find any errors. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance. Here's my code.

```
<?php
$dbc=mysqli_connect('url','username','password')
or die('error connecting');

$query = "INSERT INTO mailing_list (first_name, last_name, email_address)" . 
"VALUES ('one','two','three')";

$answer = mysqli_query($dbc,$query)
or die('error querying');


mysqli_close($dbc);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have the connection almost right but where is your database selector,also check your php extension whether it is mysql or mysqli

Answer (score 4):

You have no space in between `(first_name, last_name, email_address)` and `VALUES`. MySQL would recognize that as one word rather than two. So add that in and it should work, like this:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO mailing_list (first_name, last_name, email_address) " . 
"VALUES ('one','two','three')";
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Where isn't there a space?

Comment: @user3290281 There wasn't a space inbetween `email_address)` and `VALUES`. So it would be like `INSERT INTO mailing_list (first_name, last_name, email_address)VALUES`, and MySQL can't recognize that as two different words. So changing it to add the space will make it recognize it as two different words.

Comment: Multi-line string building with concatenation makes it far too easy to make these sorts of errors too. OP should be using a [HEREDOC](http://php.net/heredoc) for such things.